# Use Cauchy's Integral Formula to evaluate the following integral.

Tags: cauchy-sequences, complex-integration

$$\int \frac{e^z\sin z}{(2z+5i)^2} \, dz,$$ where $$\gamma$$ is a circumference of radius $5$ centered at $-4$ and traversed once in the negative (with respect to its interior) direction.

---

I've been trying to rework the fraction in the integral to make it suitable for the Cauchy integral formula.  I tried expanding the denominator into $(2z+5i)(2z+5i)$ and then I pulled out some factors from the denominator to get:

$$ \frac{\frac{e^z\sin z}{2(2z+5i)}}{z-(-\frac{5}{2i})},$$

I suspect that this is not valid because the function in the numerator fails to be analytic at the point $-5/2$ which IS in the domain.  Am I approaching this in the right way? Can anyone help me complete this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integrand $f$ has a singularity of order 2 at $z=-\frac52 i$.  To find the residue, use the following for $n=2$ and $z_0=-\frac52$

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}_{z_0}(f) &= \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}  \left((z-z_0)^n f(z)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{(2-1)!} \lim_{z \to -\frac52 i} \frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}}  \left((z+\frac52 i)^2 \frac{e^z \sin z}{(2z+5i)^2}\right) \\
&= \lim_{z \to -\frac52 i} \frac{d}{dz}  \left(\frac{e^z \sin z}{4}\right) \\
&=\frac14 \lim_{z \to -\frac52 i} e^z(\sin z +\cos z)\\
&=\frac14 e^{-i\frac52} (\sin (-i\frac52) +\cos(-i\frac52))\\
&=\frac14 \left(\cos(5/2)-i\sin(5/2)\right)\left(\cosh(5/2)-i\sinh(5/2)\right)\\
&=\frac14 \left(\cos(5/2)\cosh(5/2)-\sin(5/2)\sinh(5/2)\right)-\frac{i}{4}\left(\cos(5/2)\sinh(5/2)+\sin(5/2)\cosh(5/2)\right)
\end{align}$$

---

A second way to find the residue of $f$ is to expand the numerator in a power series at $z=-i\frac52$.  To that end, let $w=z+i\frac52$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{e^z\sin z}{(2z+i5)^2}&=\frac14\; \frac{e^{-5i/2}e^w \sin(w-i5/2)}{w^2}\\
&=\frac14 \; e^{-5i/2} \frac{(1+w+O(w^2))(\sin(-i5/2)+\cos(i5/2)w+O(w^2))}{w^2}\\
&=\frac14 \; e^{-5i/2} \left(\frac{\sin(-i5/2)}{w^2}+\frac{\sin(-i5/2)+\cos(i5/2)}{w}+O(w)\right)
\end{align}$$

from which the residue is the coefficient on the $w^{-1}$ term, namely

$$\text{Res}_{-i5/2}(f)=\frac14 e^{-5i/2} (\sin(-i5/2)+\cos(i5/2))$$

which is identical to result using the previous approach!